# Return sublevel values from object on tree menu - quasar framework

Tags: object, vue.js, treeview, quasar-framework

I trying to create multilevel tree menu from object, I want to add onClick event to get the value from the object.

```
  <p class="caption">Accordion mode</p>
  <q-tree
    :nodes="simple"
    accordion
    node-key="label"
  />
```

This is the object that populates my tree:

```
simple: [
  {
    label: 'Head',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'My Label#!', handler: (node) => this.onclick(node),
        children: [
          { 
            label: 'Sub-Label#1',handler: (node) => this.onclick(node),
            value: 'This is text#2 content from the label object'
          },
          { 
            label: 'Sub-Label#2',handler: (node) => this.onclick(node),
            value: 'This is text#2 content from the label object'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


onclick(node) {
  alert(node)
},
```

I´m using quasar Tree framework, I´m trying to onclick event to get the Value, currently my onClick event returns the node Label values, how can I add onClick to return the value from the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use .value for returning value of the node

```
onclick(node) {
  alert(node.value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patel, when I used alert(node.value), I had an typo, :( I wasn´t sure that work till you reply and came back and correct my code, thanks for the help.